# Streaming Usermodel API for writing large Excel data in Android

Tags: android, performance, apache-poi

Did somebody managed to implement apache poi library for Java called SXSSF (Streaming Usermodel API) into Android?

I want to write large xslx files, but the XSSF API crashes due to the memory leakage.

Thanks,
Toni

Comment: Did you try it? If so, how far did you get, and what problems did you hit along the way?

Comment: Hi @Gagravarr. I tried it but I think the problem is that poi SXSSF API is to big. It works with XSSF API (just poi-3.9-20121203.jar), but if you want to use SXSSF, you have to import extra libs (poi-ooxml-3.9-20121203.jar, poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9-20121203.jar, dom4j-1.6.1.jar, stax-api-1.0.1.jar, xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar). When I import this libs and want to debug my app this error appears: Unable to execute dex: "Java heap space Java heap space". (This happens if also if I just add poi-ooxml-3.9-20121203.jar and not the other jars).

Comment: I forgot to tell that the error appears in Eclipse and the application is not installed on android device.

Comment: Sounds like an Android problem then, and nothing to do with POI. I can only suggest you follow whatever advice Google/Android offer for that error message